# Why does this code fail when an int is used but not when a double is used (possible compiler bug)?

Tags: c++

Given the following very simple program in GCC 7.3.1:

```
//exponentTest.cc
#include <complex> 
#include <iostream>        

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::complex<double> iCpx = std::complex<double>(0,1); 
  double baseline[3] = {-0.1, 0, 0};
  
  double theta = atan2(baseline[1], baseline[0]); 
  std::cout << "Theta: " << theta << std::endl;

  for(size_t m =1; m < 10; m++)
    {
      std::complex<double> thetExp = exp(-1 * m * theta * iCpx); 
      std::cout << "m(" << m << "): " << thetExp << std::endl;
    }
  return 0; 
}
```

When theta is PI, this code gives an incorrect result:

```
[stix@localhost ~]$ gcc exponentTest.cc -o expTest -lm -lstdc++
[stix@localhost ~]$ ./expTest
Theta: 3.14159
m(1): (-0.963907,0.26624)
m(2): (-0.963907,0.26624)
m(3): (-0.963907,0.26624)
m(4): (-0.963907,0.26624)
m(5): (-0.963907,0.26624)
m(6): (-0.963907,0.26624)
m(7): (-0.963907,0.26624)
m(8): (-0.963907,0.26624)
m(9): (-0.963907,0.26624)
```

The correct answer should, however, be alternating +-1.

After a bit of wailing and gnashing of teeth, I tracked it down to the use of the size_t in the for() loop. I replaced it with an unsigned int, and the unit test worked, but my wider codebase where this is used didn't. Frustrated, I ultimately explicitly cast the inputs to std::exp to be double:

```
//Improved exponentTest.cc
#include <complex> 
#include <iostream> 



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::complex<double> iCpx = std::complex<double>(0,1); 
  double baseline[3] = {-0.1, 0, 0};
  
  double theta = atan2(baseline[1], baseline[0]); 
  std::cout << "Theta: " << theta << std::endl;

  for(size_t m = 1; m < 10; m++)
    {
      std::complex<double> thetExp = exp(-1 * (double)m * theta * iCpx); 
      std::cout << "m(" << m << "): " << thetExp << std::endl;
    }
  return 0; 
}
```

This version consistently gives the correct result:

```
[stix@localhost ~]$ gcc exponentTest.cc -o expTest -lm -lstdc++
[stix@localhost ~]$ ./expTest
Theta: 3.14159
m(1): (-1,-1.22465e-16)
m(2): (1,2.44929e-16)
m(3): (-1,-3.67394e-16)
m(4): (1,4.89859e-16)
m(5): (-1,-6.12323e-16)
m(6): (1,7.34788e-16)
m(7): (-1,-8.57253e-16)
m(8): (1,9.79717e-16)
m(9): (-1,-1.10218e-15)
```

So problem solved. However, I don't know why the problem occurred in the first place, and it somewhat smells of a compiler bug. The worst part is that the problem is inconsistent without the explicit cast of m in the exp() function; sometimes it provides correct results, other times it doesn't.

My understanding is that the C++ standard requires that a compiler automatically cast all ints to doubles in something like the line:

```
double = int * double * int * double;
```

But the compiler is clearly not doing this.

Is this a compiler bug or is there some gotcha I'm not thinking about in mixing doubles and ints?

**Edit: Per one of the comments the exponent line should throw a warning since an unsigned type is being multiplied by -1, however, that is not the case:**

```
[stix@localhost ~]$ gcc exponentTest.cc -o expTest -lm -lstdc++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors
exponentTest.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
exponentTest.cc:6:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
              ^~~~
exponentTest.cc:6:27: warning: unused parameter ‘argv’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
                           ^~~~
```

Relevant software versions (I'm using devtoolset-7 for GCC 7):

```
[stix@localhost ~]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[stix@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
[stix@localhost ~]$ rpm -qa | grep devtoolset
devtoolset-7-gcc-plugin-devel-7.3.1-5.16.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-binutils-2.28-11.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-gcc-7.3.1-5.16.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-gcc-gfortran-7.3.1-5.16.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-runtime-7.1-4.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-libquadmath-devel-7.3.1-5.16.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-gcc-gdb-plugin-7.3.1-5.16.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-libstdc++-devel-7.3.1-5.16.el7.x86_64
devtoolset-7-gcc-c++-7.3.1-5.16.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: `m` is `size_t` which is an unsigned type. Multiplying by -1 should probably give you a warning. I'd suggest turning up your warning level.

Comment: @ChrisMM Fair point, but since there's a double in there shouldn't the compiler be casting the whole thing to doubles? Isn't that the C standard?

Comment: @KamilCuk OK, Chris says it should give at the minimum a warning, which it doesn't even on -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors

Comment: GCC note: You can often get more warnings if you tell the compiler to look at the code more deeply by turning on optimizations. The quick glace of a typical debug build can miss subtle errors the optimizer makes obvious.

Comment: The warning option you're looking for is `-Wsign-conversion`. I found this by using `-Weverything` in Clang, getting a relevant warning, noting the warning option provided in the message, and trying it in GCC since Clang is pretty compatible with GCC.

Comment: Just a note on terminology: there are no **casts** involved in that expression. There are **implicit conversions**. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest fix is to change `1` to `1.0`. That forces the computations to be done with `double`s:

```
std::complex<double> thetExp = exp(-1.0 * m * theta * iCpx);
```

Why is that? Let's take a look at the failing expression:

```
-1 * m * theta * iCpx
```

The types here are:

```
int * size_t * double * std::complex<double>
```

C++ doesn't look at all the types and pick the "highest" to promote everything to. Instead, it looks at the binary operations one by one, left-to-right, as if there were parentheses grouping them like:

```
(((int * size_t) * double) * std::complex<double>)
```

You get in trouble because `int * size_t` is performed first. Integer promotion rules apply and the `int` is converted to `size_t` since on your platform `size_t` is larger. This means a signed 32-bit integer is being converted to a 64-bit unsigned integer.

Try this and you can see the problem:

```
std::cout << (size_t) -1 << "\n";
```

It prints:

```
18446744073709551615
```

When you changed `-1 * m` to `-1 * (double) m` that got rid of the signed/unsigned problem. `-1` was promoted to a `double` which is simply `-1.0`.

Comment: As someone else pointed out, shouldn't the code at least throw a warning since there's a signed type being multiplied by an unsigned?

Comment: I agree it should. It's unfortunate that `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` doesn't produce a warning. I don't blame you for missing the problem.

Comment: @stix Yes - clang-cl (in Visual Studio) *does* warn about this (see the edit to my answer).

Comment: clang++ on Linux misses this, too.

Comment: The conversion to `size_t` happens even if that type is the *same* size as an `int`, IIRC. (Something about *no such thing as a negative integer literal*?)

Comment: ... but, in the case of a 32-bit `size_t` (or, as OP tried, using `unsigned int`), it seems that values like `4294967295` can be *accurately* represented as `double` and the problem ***seems*** to go away (but it doesn't really).

Answer (score 3):

The multiplication operator (`*`) has left-to-right associativity. Thus, in your argument expression:

```cpp
exp(-1 * m * theta * iCpx)
```

The `-1 * m` is performed *first* and is done using the `size_t` type. This will result in a **very** large number (due to `-1` being interpreted as an *unsigned* constant) which, when converted/cast to a `double` will almost certainly lose precision.

Adding some diagnostics to your loop reveals the problem in all its glory:

```cpp
for (size_t m = 1; m < 10; m++) {
    std::cout << (-1 * m) << " " << (-1 * (double)m) << std::endl; // Diagnostic!
    std::complex<double> thetExp = exp(-1 * m * theta * iCpx);
    std::cout << "m(" << m << "): " << thetExp << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Theta: 3.14159
18446744073709551615 -1
m(1): (-0.963907,0.26624)
18446744073709551614 -2
m(2): (-0.963907,0.26624)
18446744073709551613 -3
m(3): (-0.963907,0.26624)
18446744073709551612 -4
m(4): (-0.963907,0.26624)
18446744073709551611 -5
m(5): (-0.963907,0.26624)
18446744073709551610 -6
m(6): (-0.963907,0.26624)
18446744073709551609 -7
m(7): (-0.963907,0.26624)
18446744073709551608 -8
m(8): (-0.963907,0.26624)
18446744073709551607 -9
m(9): (-0.963907,0.26624)
```

Explicitly casting `m` to a `double` forces that initial multiplication to be (correctly) performed in double-precision arithmetic. (Note: casting `m` to a (signed) `int` will also work.)

---

Note that clang-cl warns about this:

> warning : implicit conversion changes signedness: 'int' to 'unsigned
> long long' [-Wsign-conversion]

Comment: Note that OP's attempt using a (presumably, 32-bit) `unsigned int` for `m` only ***appears*** to work. The `-1 * m` is *still* performed as an `unsigned int` operation but, then the resultant values (around 4294967295) can be *accurately* represented as `double`. I'm just surprised that the `exp` function seems to handle those, however (I tested on my MSVC using a 32-bit build with `size_t`).